# modbus RTU (RS484) packet frame decoding

Tags: modbus

I have captured the protocol analyzer logs from RS485 serial connection between RTU device and the equipment which is to be monitored. I am newbee to this. I have read through Modbus and RS485. Found that every frame will have Slave address, Function code, DATA and CRS with start and end of the frame of 305 charcaters. I am trying to decode the protocol analyzer logs but unable to get theu clue. Please help me on this.

These are the logs which I need to understand

=============================================================

```
Record =          1         05.23.15  13:29:29.000000000  
                 RTS:OFF  DTR:OFF  CTS:OFF  DSR:OFF  CD:ON   
Record =          2  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.127439596  00  NUL 
Record =          3  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.127986496  37  7   
Record =          4  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.128741696  17  ETB 
Record =          5  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.129184396  ED  ... 
Record =          6  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.129757296  F2  ... 
Record =          7  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.130486496  FD  ... 
Record =          8  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.131007296  D5  ... 
Record =          9  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.559109485  91  ... 
Record =         10  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.559630385  10  DLE 
Record =         11  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.560151185  2F  /   
Record =         12  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.560678485  B0  ... 
Record =         13  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.561199385  00  NUL 
Record =         14  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.561720185  01  SOH 
Record =         15  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.562247485  02  STX 
Record =         16  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.562768385  00  NUL 
Record =         17  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.563289185  01  SOH 
Record =         18  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.563816485  0F  SI  
Record =         19  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.564337385  64  d  

Record =         20  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.707291982  00  NUL 
Record =         21  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.707838882  37  7   
Record =         22  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.708594082  17  ETB 
Record =         23  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.709036682  ED  ... 
Record =         24  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.709609682  F2  ... 
Record =         25  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.710338782  FD  ... 
Record =         26  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:29.710859682  D5  ... 
Record =         27  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.142926671  91  ... 
Record =         28  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.143447471  10  DLE 
Record =         29  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.143974871  2F  /   
Record =         30  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.144495671  B0  ... 
Record =         31  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.145016471  00  NUL 
Record =         32  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.145543871  01  SOH 
Record =         33  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.146064671  02  STX 
Record =         34  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.146585471  00  NUL 
Record =         35  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.147112871  01  SOH 
Record =         36  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.147633671  0F  SI  
Record =         37  (DCE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.148154470  64  d


Record =         38  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.287254967  00  NUL 

Record =         39  (DTE)  05.23.15  13:29:30.287801867  37  7 

=============================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the time stamps, this seems to be one message:
`91 10 2F B0 00 01 02 00 01 0F 64`. It actually appears twice in your log.

The interpretation should be:

- `91` Slave address (145 dec)
- `10` Function code (16 dec) = Write registers
- `2F` Start address (Most significant byte)
- `B0` Start address (Least significant byte)
- `00` Number of registers (Most significant byte)
- `01` Number of registers (Least significant byte)
- `02` Byte count (2 bytes will follow)
- `00` Data (Most significant byte)
- `01` Data (Least significant byte)
- `0F` CRC (checksum)
- `64` CRC (checksum)

It is a message from the master (computer) to a slave (instrument). Basically it says: Write one register on instrument with slave address 145. The register address is 2FB0 (hex), and the data value is 0001 (hex).

I have written about how to interpret Modbus RTU messages in the documentation of my Python Minimalmodbus module:

- https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.org/en/master/modbusdetails.html
- https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.org/en/master/debugmode.html

What information register 2FB0 (hex) holds is described in the documentation of your instrument.